# Joining a CTE Based On Number of Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
WITH vTable1 AS (
SELECT PartNumber
FROM Inventory
WHERE Quantity > 1 
)

SELECT 
    [A whole bunch of conditions for tags] +
    CASE WHEN vTable1.PartNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS 'TagValue'
FROM Inventory
LEFT JOIN vTable1 ON Inventory.PartNumber = vTable1.PartNumber
```

So this is a very general example of what I am trying to do so bear with me.

The idea is in my CTE, I have a set of conditions that return a list of PartNumbers back. I I want to add a tag value only if there are more than 10 PartNumbers that are returned to me. Otherwise, just leave it blank.

The current way I have it set up joins vTable1 without taking the number of rows into account.

How would I go about only adding a tag value if the CTE has more than 10 rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be using the count in a subquery:

```
WITH vTable1 AS (
    SELECT PartNumber
    FROM Inventory
    WHERE Quantity > 1 
)
SELECT 
    [A whole bunch of conditions for tags] +
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM vTable1 AS X) >= 10 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS 'TagValue'
FROM Inventory
LEFT JOIN vTable1 ON Inventory.PartNumber = vTable1.PartNumber
```

Another would be using a windowed `COUNT()` in the CTE.

```
WITH vTable1 AS (
    SELECT PartNumber, TotalParts = COUNT(1) OVER()
    FROM Inventory
    WHERE Quantity > 1 
)
SELECT 
    [A whole bunch of conditions for tags] +
    CASE WHEN vTable1.TotalParts >= 10 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS 'TagValue'
FROM Inventory
LEFT JOIN vTable1 ON Inventory.PartNumber = vTable1.PartNumber
```

Comment: Thanks! Both ways work beautifully. This was the idea I thought of but didn't know how to implement it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use if / then logic

```
If [your condition]
begin

SELECT 
    [A whole bunch of conditions for tags] +
    [ADD TAG]'TagValue'
FROM Inventory
LEFT JOIN vTable1 ON Inventory.PartNumber = vTable1.PartNumber

end


else
begin 

SELECT 
    [A whole bunch of conditions for tags] +
   [no tag added]
FROM Inventory
LEFT JOIN vTable1 ON Inventory.PartNumber = vTable1.PartNumber


end
```

Comment: This is assuming your entire result set is dependant on how many lines the CTE returns